# Best practice recursive flattening of linked list in c#

Tags: c#, linq, linked-list

I built a data structure where the main class, `TaskHolder`,
contains a `List<Task>` and `Task` contains another `List<Task>` and `Name`.
is there a LINQ one line code that can retrieve all nested Names into a flattened string array?

this is the basic structure:

```
Public class TaskHolder
  List<Task>

Public class Task
  String Name
  List<Task>
```

Comment: So it is possible to unlimited nested levels?

Comment: @PetSerAl you took the words out of my mouth

Comment: Absence of cycles are guaranteed?

Comment: This is only one example of a duplicate. The "LINQ recusive one-liner" is asked at least once every two weeks.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you can't achieve it without recursion. It can be something like this:

```
    static IEnumerable<string> Flatten(Task task)
    {
        return new[] {task.Name}.Concat(task.Tasks.SelectMany(Flatten));
    }

    //.. and then
    var allNames = Flatten(taskHolder.Task);
```

Comment: @MartinLiversage and why shouldn't recursion look recursive? ;)

Comment: Works like a charm. I encapsulated this Helper with a for each loop to iterate all tasks in the list and concatanated it all into a IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write your own LINQ extension method to do this kind of thing, and use something like a stack to avoid explicit recursion (better if the nesting is very deep):

```
  public static class LinqExtensions
  {
    public static IEnumerable<TP> FlattenProperties<T, TP>(this IEnumerable<T> outers,
        Func<T, TP> propertySelector, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> innersSelector)
    {
      Stack<T> stack = new Stack<T>(outers);
      while (stack.Any())
      {
        T outer = stack.Pop();

        TP prop = propertySelector(outer);
        yield return prop;
        if (innersSelector(outer) != null)
        {
          foreach (var inner in innersSelector(outer))
            stack.Push(inner);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

You can then write something like:

```
TaskHolder th = new TaskHolder() { ... };
var names = th.Tasks.FlattenProperties(x => x.Name, x => x.Tasks).ToList();
```